# If we set a textbox's text property by code in runtime, does Textchanged event handler fire?

Tags: asp.net, textbox

In a .aspx web page, by setting a textbox's text property by code in run time, will Textchanged event handler of that textbox be fired?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it doesn't.

You might want to put the code of your TextChanged event in a separate method so that you can call it manually after you change the Text property.